# Xcode 8 beta 6: AnyObject replaced by Any: where is classForCoder?

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8-beta6

Xcode 8 beta 6 has replaced `AnyObject` by `Any`.

In some cases I used `a.classForCoder` for debugging reasons to see what's in it. With `AnyObject` this worked. With `Any` this doesn't work any more.

Now that I have to use `Any`: what is the preferred way to see what type is in a variable of type `Any`?

Casting to `AnyObject` appears not to be very useful since in many cases this is a `String` and `String` doesn't confirm to `AnyObject` any more since Xcode 8 beta 6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Using type(of:)

You can use `type(of:)` to find out what type of variable is in a variable of type `Any`.

```
let a: Any = "hello"
print(type(of: a))  // String

let b: Any = 3.14
print(type(of: b))  // Double

import Foundation
let c: Any = "hello" as NSString
print(type(of: c))  // __NSCFString

let d: Any = ["one": 1, "two": "two"]
print(type(of: d))  //  Dictionary<String, Any>

struct Person { var name = "Bill" }
let e: Any = Person()
print(type(of: e))  // Person
```

---

#### Using classForCoder

`classForCoder` is still there, and you can cast a value of type `Any` to `AnyObject`, but if the value is a Swift value type, you'll get a converted result and not the original type:

```
import Foundation // or import UIKit or import Cocoa

let f: Any = "bye"
print((f as AnyObject).classForCoder)  // NSString
print(type(of: f))                     // String

let g: Any = 2
print((g as AnyObject).classForCoder)  // NSNumber
print(type(of: g))                     // Int

let h: Any = [1: "one", 2: 2.0]
print((h as AnyObject).classForCoder)  // NSDictionary
print(type(of: h))                     // Dictionary<Int, Any>

struct Dog { var name = "Orion" }
let i: Any = Dog()
print((i as AnyObject).classForCoder)  // _SwiftValue
print(type(of: i))                     // Dog

// For an object, the result is the same
let j: Any = UIButton()
print((j as AnyObject).classForCoder)  // UIButton
print(type(of: j))                     // UIButton
```